# phantom access website and got page with title "Welcome To Zscaler Directory Authentication"

Tags: phantomjs

Here is my code,

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com', function() {
  page.render('example.png');

});
```

Here is what I got

```
------------
Welcome To Zscaler Directory Authentication
------------
Authenticating user to the Web Security Service
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: First, have you tried just to get it through HTTPS? I see *http* in your sample. Second, do you have an idea why it navigates to http://www.zscaler.com/

Comment: @AndreyBorisko, HTTPS does not work, and the navigation or redirection should be a policy of our network, even using web browser at least the first time, i'm not sure if still needs redirection or not after the first time authentication success